# Maximum execution time issue in wideimage library of symfony 2

Tags: symfony

Following error is coming

FatalErrorException: Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/proto/vendor/wideimage/wideimage/lib/WideImage/Operation/Resize.php line 151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `max_execution_time` parameter. You can do it in php.ini or with next code:

```
set_time_limit(0); // will set it to 'No time limit'
                   // To limit time for N seconds you need to replace 0 by N
```

Comment: thanks can we set this code via some config file of symfony 2

Comment: If you want to execute every request with no time limit you need to put this line in `app.php` in the web directory